# Wifi connection not working with VPN using UDP, EPN protocol, but fine with VPN using TCP protocol

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, tcp, udp

I have a wifi connection (MobyKlick) in my appartment which has **no router** available for configuration.

The internet works fine as long as I'm not connected to a VPN network using either the UDP or EPN protocol. Setting the VPN network to use TCP protocol works fine.

But the problem is one of my VPN network belongs to the company I'm working at and can't be configured. The problem definitely lies in the settings of the network as I've tried multiple devices using multiple networks and it fails only when I'm at home using this specific network, trying to connect to that VPN of my company which uses the ESP protocol.

What could be the problem? And what should I do to make this network work with my company's VPN.

Comment: That’s a very broad question. Apparently the quality of connection is not up to par or is being filtered in some way as to cause you problems. It’s not possible to provide more than a general idea of the issue and the only recommendation is to get a different ISP at home as it sounds like you have no control over the network you are currently using.

Comment: Could you clarify which VPN type you're using? UDP and TCP themselves are _not_ VPN protocols, they're transport protocols which carry some VPN protocol inside. (And must say I haven't heard of a protocol called "EPN" at all... ESP?)

Comment: Some routers allow limiting traffic to TCP on 80/443 (see [FRITZ!Box guest access](https://service.avm.de/help/en/FRITZ-Box-7390-avme/014/hilfe_wlan_gast) for example) and some VPN servers are configured to work with TCP on 80/443 to *disguise* their traffic as HTTP. So maybe its the case with your router?

Comment: @YanFoto That's possible. What should I do?

Comment: You cannot do anything if you don't have access to the router and open ports.